# Identify P2P hardware available in device

Tags: android, nfc-p2p

Is there any way to identify whether NFC p2p hardware available or not in device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Code for identifying NFC P2P available or not in Android Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345812/android-code-for-identifying-nfc-p2p-available-or-not-in-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

First you can check out your device on the manufacturers website, or via Google, to get all the technical infos about it.

But (at least on Android) you can also go into your system settings, and there you should be able to activate things like Bluetooth or NFC, if you have them.